# How do I setState after first setState is complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update my edit state once mapProps is complete. My edit state is set with true, in the constructor, but I want to change it to false after mapProps. My console reads that edit is still set to true after my condition has been met. Why is this not working? Thank you in advance!

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.mapProps();
  }

  mapProps = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        items: this.props.items,
        name: this.props.name,
        unit: this.props.unit,
        price: this.props.price,
        avail: this.props.avail
      },
      () => {
        this.editMap();
      }
    );
  };

  editMap = () => {

    if (!this.state.name === "") {
      this.setState({
        edit: false
      });
    }

  };


render() {
    const { name, unit, price, avail } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {!this.state.delete ? (
          <div className="edit-bar">
            <div className="left">
              <div className="fields">
                <h1>Product</h1>
                {!this.state.edit ? (
                  <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
                ) : (
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  ></input>
                )})
```

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement in `editMap()` is wrong. It would always be false, so the next setState, which sets the edit to false, would never be invoked.

In your if statement, `!this.state.name` would return a boolean value, which you are trying to check against empty string. So it would always be false.

Change it to `if(this.state.name !== "")` or even better `if(!this.state.name)`